# How to separate docker build and publish scripts into separate stages in Gitlab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-image

I would like to build and publish docker images in two separate stages:

- build
- publish

Unfortunately, Gitlab runs those stages inside different workers - `ci-runner-worker11` and `ci-runner-worker15`. Therefore images built in the first stage are not visible in the second stage. Do you know a clean solution to have this separation and be able to pass those artifacts between stages?

I've tried this solution:

```
container_images:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  image: ...
...

push_images:
  stage: publish
  dependencies: 
- container_images
...
```

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
untracked: found 170 files                         
ERROR: Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... too large archive  id=15085670 responseStatus=413 Request Entity Too Large status=413
FATAL: too large
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need this? Maybe there is a better solution.

`untracked` artifacts are relative to the project root folder, and the docker build command will store the image layers elsewhere.

If you need to test the container before setting a final tag, you can:

- Use a temp tag
- Push it to the repository
- Test the image (with the temp tag)
- If all tests pass, change the tag and push it again to the repository
- If the test fails, remove the test image.

You can use a fixed temp tag, but you need to be sure that you only run one pipeline at a time. Or, you can use a temp tag based on the `CI_PIPELINE_ID` environment variable.

Comment: For clarity. I would like to instantly know whether there was a problem during building a image or during pushing it to a repository.

Comment: You can create a script and save the exit status of each command and maybe some error messages (using regex). You can also save relevant information as artifacts to check later. In the end, apply the logic you want and finish the script with success or fail status.

Answer (score 1):

In the build phase save/export<sup>*</sup> the docker image as a tarball:

```
docker save ${IMAGE} | gzip > saved-docker-image.tgz
```

and add the tarball to the artifacts list:

```
container_images:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - saved-docker-image.tgz
  image: ...
...
```

Then in the publish/deploy phase load/import<sup>*</sup> the tarball:

```
cat saved-docker-image.tgz | gunzip | docker load
```

You can then push the image to your container registry like normal (for example):

```
docker push ${IMAGE}
```

<sup>*</sup> Please note that there is a difference between save/load and export/import.  If you want to keep the layers and all the rest of the docker context then use save/load, if you just want a flat image then use export/import.